# Way to begin a story ,joke etc

Tags: meaning-in-context

How should i start to tell story , joke etc.. For example is it correct to say : There is story that goes that a man walks into a bar... ? Or can make it without using goes that .

Comment: If I were telling this joke to my friends, they would all recognize "A man walks into a bar" as the introduction to a joke, because it's a cliche. You could guess whether your audience would recognize such a formula, and also ask yourself whether you want them to know immediately that they're hearing a joke, and decide accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to introduce a joke or story. The most straightforward is to say, "I heard a funny joke the other day." Then tell the joke. Like, "I heard a funny joke the other day. A priest, a rabbi, and an auto mechanic go into a bar and ..."

There are many possible lead-ins like that. "That reminds me of a joke." "Have you heard this one?" Etc.

Usually you just go from the introduction to telling the story. You don't need to say "it goes like this" or any such. Just tell the story.

If you're sitting around swapping jokes and stories, you often don't need any lead in. Just tell the story.

My father used to introduce jokes as if they were true stories. He'd casually say, "Today a guy at work ..." "Once when I was driving to New York ..." or some such. It wasn't until he told the punch line that you realized this was a joke and not a true story, and then of course his listeners would moan.